# Fill scala column with nulls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am getting the error `Caused by: scala.MatchError: Null (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)` when I try to fill a DataFrame with null values to replace other values in it. How can I do this using Scala Spark 2.1?

Comment: How are you doing it? Show some example code? normally `na.fill()` should work if you want to replace null with a single value.

Comment: Sorry - I want to replace the value with null ie. something is 0 and I want it to be null instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isin` and [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions%24@when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column). Required imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
```

Example data:

```
val toReplace = Seq("foo", "bar")

val df = Seq((1, "Jane"), (2, "foo"), (3, "John"), (4, "bar")).toDF("id", "name")
```

Query:

```
df.withColumn("name", when(!$"name".isin(toReplace: _*), $"name")).
```

and the result:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|Jane|
|  2|null|
|  3|John|
|  4|null|
+---+----+
```